# DynamodB query starts taking more time when we put more data into table

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

We have a dynamoDb table with following structure.

```
userId - partition key- number
yearOfBirth -attribute number
dateOfBirth - attribute(number in millisecond)
loginTime - attribute(number in millisecond)
```

and with following gsi -  user_gsi

```
yearOfBirth - partition key- number
dateOfBirth - sort key (number -in millisecond)
loginTime - attribute(number in millisecond)
```

we are using java aws sdk to query the table.
Our query requirement is to query all users between two dateOfBirth and between two loginTime.
We get all year from dateofBirth range and query for each year in separate thread and later join the result returned by each thread.

Following code is used to query for a single yearOfBirth-

```
public Set<Long> queryForSingleBirthYear(Long startDateDob, Long endDateDob,Long minLoginTime, Long maxLoginTime, int yearOfBirth){
        Set<Long> userIds = new HashSet<>();

        Map<String, AttributeValue> lastEvaluatedKey = null;
        do{
            QueryRequest queryRequest = new QueryRequest().withTableName("user");
            queryRequest
                    .withIndexName("user_gsi")
                    .withExclusiveStartKey(lastEvaluatedKey);

            Condition keyCond = new Condition().withComparisonOperator(ComparisonOperator.EQ)
                    .withAttributeValueList(new AttributeValue().withN(Integer.toString(yearOfBirth)));

            String startDate = startDateDob.toString();
            String endDate = endDateDob.toString();

            Condition dobCond = new Condition().withComparisonOperator(ComparisonOperator.BETWEEN)
                    .withAttributeValueList(new AttributeValue().withN(startDate), new AttributeValue().withN(endDate));

            Map<String, Condition> keyCondMap = new HashMap<>();
            keyCondMap.put("yearOfBirth", keyCond);
            keyCondMap.put("dateOfBirth", dobCond);

            queryRequest.setKeyConditions(keyCondMap);
            Map<String,String> attrNames = new HashMap<>();
            attrNames.put("#loginTime","loginTime");
            Map<String,AttributeValue> attrvalues = new HashMap<>();
            attrvalues.put(":v_minLoginTime",new AttributeValue().withN(minLoginTime.toString()));
            attrvalues.put(":v_maxLoginTime",new AttributeValue().withN(maxLoginTime.toString()));

            String queryFilter = "#loginTime > :v_minLoginTime and #loginTime <= :v_maxLoginTime";

            queryRequest.withFilterExpression(queryFilter)
                    .withExpressionAttributeNames(attrNames)
                    .withExpressionAttributeValues(attrvalues);;

            QueryResult queryResult = amazonDynamoDB.query(queryRequest);
            List<Map<String, AttributeValue>> items = queryResult.getItems();
            for (Map<String, AttributeValue> item : items) {
                String id = item.get("userId").getN();
                userIds.add(Long.valueOf(id));
            }
            lastEvaluatedKey = queryResult.getLastEvaluatedKey();
        }while (lastEvaluatedKey != null);
        return basicFilterRes;
    }
```

While doing our load testing our queries starts taking time as we load more data into the table.
For 200K records and around and an dateOfBirth range of having around 25 yearOfBirth it takes approximate 2-3 seconds.
If we increase the number of records to 1.5 million in table it starts taking around 15-20 seconds. We have tried increasing RCU and even changing RCU to on demand mode, but time remains same.

**EDIT**

Following are the results after printing time taken by query for each year-

```
yearOfBirth=1972, resultSize=110, timeMs=56
yearOfBirth=1977, resultSize=199, timeMs=54
yearOfBirth=1971, resultSize=89, timeMs=59
yearOfBirth=1973, resultSize=113, timeMs=60
yearOfBirth=1974, resultSize=143, timeMs=60
yearOfBirth=1978, resultSize=266, timeMs=59
yearOfBirth=1998, resultSize=3524, timeMs=612
yearOfBirth=1993, resultSize=3923, timeMs=677
yearOfBirth=1995, resultSize=4569, timeMs=714
yearOfBirth=1994, resultSize=4688, timeMs=777
```

Comment: event if you are able to make it work, it will not be very performant, since most of your use case are join, you should probably use sql db instead of nosql  one

Answer (score 1):

What is the loginTime range? Consider switching the gsi to index on loginTime if it is narrower than the dateOfBirth range.

With 1.5 million records and 25 year queries, each query will have to read about 60,000 records which will take some time since each page is loaded serially. You can parallelize each year query by querying for a part of each year at the same time by splitting the range between `startDateDob` and `endDateDob` into smaller non-overlapping ranges. e.g. if startDateDob and endDateDob cover a whole year, split into 12 queries, one for each month.

Comment: We ran our code and printed time taken by query for each year, results are attached in edit. As you can see clearly from results that some year contains more records, for these year time taken by query also increases. Our impression from dynamoDB was that it will not increase query latency even if data increases in a partition by taking more RCU.

Comment: How times do the longer queries paginate? If you split and parallelize the per year queries you can obtain the speed you need.